# Print out array list

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print out an array list, I have the code however its only ever printing the last list added twice and not the two different lists.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: turns out I had Static in my Auction class *face palm*
Thanks for helping out the newby!

```
        System.out.println("--Items for Sale--");
    Date closeDate = new Date();


    ArrayList<Auction> objects = new ArrayList<Auction>();

    objects.add(new Auction("T-Shirt", "New Red T-Shirt", 0.99, 5.00, 'O'));
    objects.add(new Auction("Top", "New Red Top", 0.99, 5.00, 'O'));

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(objects.get(i));
    }
```

Output:

```
Item: Top, Description: New Red Top, Start Price: 0.99, Reserve Price: 5.00 ,Status: O
Item: Top, Description: New Red Top, Start Price: 0.99, Reserve Price: 5.00 ,Status: O
```

Comment: Are you sure?...

Comment: override method toString in Auction class

Comment: Please add the code of `Auction`, I'm afraid there may be some very nasty `static` keyword somewhere.

Comment: Plot twist. It's all static.

Comment: static twist, it's all plot.

Comment: I removed the static keywords, thanks peeps. It's a newby here

Comment: twist static, it's plot all

Comment: Static plot, it's all twist.